# Details on _doserrno (MSVC) much-needed

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, msdn

I found that documentation on MSVC's **`_doserrno`** global variable is very "sparse", so to say. Its existence is mentioned in the documentation for **`errno`**, the Standard C global variable for error codes. At the same time **`_doserrno`** seems to be an MSVC extension. The documentation mentions that it *may* provide additional information on I/O errors, but it also says most functions do **not** set it.

But what functions *do* set it? There doesn't seem to be a list for this, or did I miss anything? In the documentation for individual functions I also do **not** see any mention like "this function does [not] set `_doserrno`". So how do I know whether a function does set it or not? Very confusing, isn't it?

Furthermore, the documentation doesn't say a word about how the values of **`_doserrno`** have to be interpreted. If figured, from my own testing, that it's just the Win32 Error Code passed through from the Win32 API to the C API. But is this always the case? And how to convert `_doserrno` to string?

(I know I could use `FormatMessage()` directly from Win32 API to get a string from Win32 Error Codes. But reverting to the Win32 API totally contradicts the purose of having `_doserrno` in the C API!)

Regards,
MuldeR

Comment: Why do you need `_doserrno` on the first place? Judging from its name it is has been deprecated long ago.

Comment: Because **`errno`** only has some "standard" OS-agnostic error codes that are *very generic*. It often just returns `EACCES` or `EIO` for a whole class of different errors. With **`_doserrno`** we can get more detailed info, like "file is already open in another process" and the like...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use native functions directly if you need native error codes? Note that your last statement about having `_doserrno` in the C API is actually wrong as it is actually a Microsoft extension.

Comment: Well, I want to stick to Standard C function as much as possible, so that my code is portable between Windows and POSIX. Unfortunately behavior is sometimes different between these platforms. For example, `fopen()` on POSIX *can* open directories(!), while MSVC implementation fails with rather misleading `EACCES` error in that case! So, for example, I want to get the "real" reason for `fopen()` to fail via `_doserrno`, in order to present a less misleading error message to the user.

Comment: It retains its original intention, it stores the underlying OS error code.  No longer the MS-Dos error of old, today the winapi error code.  Whether that is *consistently* done correctly is something you'll have to find out, you can't get a warranty here.  Either by testing or by reading the CRT source code.  Look in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source directory for VS versions >= 2015.

Comment: It's unfortunate that I have to figure it out myself. The Win32 API has at least three different types of errors codes - Win32 Error, NTSTATUS and HRESULT - which ***might*** be returned as "underlying OS error code". And it's *not* even clear which "C" API functions do set `_doserrno` at all, let alone the type exact of error code. Things might even change over time when MSVCRT is updated. Oh well...

Comment: BTW: It is next to impossible to figure out which "C" API functions do set `_doserrno` from the CRT source code. That is because if you look at the "public" functions (like `fread()`), you will notice that these may *not* reference `_doserrno` directly, but call into a zillion of "internal" sub-functions (which in turn call into more deeply nested sub-functions) where eventually `_doserrno` might be set - or not. The heavy usage of "internal" CRT macros in the CRT code doesn't simply the analysis either...

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s impossible to do what you want.

If you want to stick to portable C functions for IO, you won’t get sensible error codes or messages: neither C nor C++ standard library expose that stuff.

And if you want good error messages on Windows, you have to use Win32 API instead of portable C functions. BTW, there’re good OO wrappers above that, e.g. see [CAtlFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtezkk30.aspx) for files.

Comment: Well, I want to stick with portable C functions as much as possible. Implementing my own platform-specific functions or using extra libraries is **not** desired. However, using `_doserrno` instead of `errno` on the Windows platform could easily be accomplished by a single `#define` at the top of the file - and all the rest of the code could remain 100% portable C. But currently it is uncertain if all Standard C function I use will set `_doserrno` (on the Windows platform), and also how to print `_doserrno` as string - without having to include `<Windows.h>` - which brings in a bloated mess...

Comment: @MuldeR File IO is not portable between Windows and POSIX. A trivial example, if you keep your file names in const char*, it may fail on Windows in runtime for non-ASCII names; if they’re const wchar_t*, it won’t compile on POSIX. There’re other important differences: timestamps, compression, attributes, sparse files, security, hard & symbolic links, all that stuff is very different between these platforms.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's why I use `#define`'s to replace **`fopen()`** with **`wfopen()`** on the Windows platform. So, some platform-specific `#define`'s are required to enable Unicode filename support on the Windows platform, but the actual "business logic" code remains portable. Reverting to the Win32 API would require writing (and maintaining) completely different code for each platform...

Comment: @MuldeR And by not supporting different code you’ll get sub-par quality on Windows. There’s no easy way around that. QT might help as it already contains 2 different implementations with same API (QFile),  but that thing is huge and for some applications very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness since I just looked into this:

Look at the mapping in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source<SDKver>\ucrt\misc\errno.cpp

```
struct errentry
{
    unsigned long oscode; // OS return value
    int errnocode;        // System V error code
};
```

These are the only mappings used between CRT error codes and OS error codes. Not all CRT error codes are mapped and just a fraction of the OS error codes. To get more detail and probably the real error you need to use the Windows SDK.